# Changing the value of a variable between two values

Tags: ruby

In ruby, is there any method for changing the value of a variable between two values based on its current value?
I need something like this:

```
var = 'value one'
var.flip('value one', 'value two')
puts var # => 'value two'
```

So when I call `.flip` it changes the value of `var` to `'value two'`, because the current value of `var` is `'value one'`

Comment: Why not `var = v2`? The function you are asking seems to be the assignment operator. If you are talking of an object attributes, it is different, though.

Comment: An object can't become another object.

Comment: Regarding your edit: what happens with `v1` and `v2`, are they flipped, too?

Comment: Let's assume `v1 = "foo"` and `var = v1`. When calling `var.flip`, you actually call `"foo".flip`. It's not possible for `"foo"` to change a local variable. And it doesn't make much sense from an OOP perspective, either. The only way to change a variable is via assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) enumerator:

```
values = ['value one', 'value two'].cycle
#=> #<Enumerator: ["value one", "value two"]:cycle>
```

And call [`next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to cycle through the values:

```
var = values.next
#=> "value one"

var = values.next
#=> "value two"

var = values.next
#=> "value one"
```

Comment: Nice answer. But there is a problem: `var` has an initial value.

Comment: Sajjad, there's no problem. What Stefan means is this: `var = "cat"; values = [var, "dog"].cycle #=> #<Enumerator: ["cat", "dog"]:cycle>; var = values.next #=> "cat"; var = values.next #=> "dog"; var = values.next #=> "cat"` and so on.

Comment: @Sajjad it would certainly help if you could provide more details. Explain your use-case and why you want / have to change the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the ruby ternary operator or the if - else contruction like this

```
var1 = 2

var1 = 3 == var1 ? var1 : 2
```

or

```
irb(main):049:0> var1 = if 4 == var1 then var1 else 2 end
=> 4
i
```